# How to draw connector between shapes by dragging in wpf c#

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, visual-studio-2012, wpf-4.0

I want to do this in wpf c# draw connector between shapes when drag from shape to another draw connector
like this image 'http://postimg.org/image/5uhua41lx/'

Comment: [What have you tried](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)?

Comment: connector between two uielements